# Xamarin Android App closed after taking a photo during the Debug Mode

Tags: c#, android, android-intent, camera, xamarin.android

I have written a sample Android Application from a Youtube Video. This App takes a photo and displays it on the Activity with the help of the Image View. I use Visual Studio Community 2015 with Xamarin.

If I select the Debug Mode and run my App, the app will be closed after taking a picture via Camera Intent.

But If I normally open my Sample App on my Phone, the app won't be closed after taking a photo.

Although I inserted this piece of code in the method "onActivityResult":

```
if (!Debug.IsDebuggerConnected)
{
    Debug.WaitForDebugger();
    Log.Debug("Debug", "Debug Starts");
}
```

and put a breakpoint on Log...., it doesn't work.

What is the reason?

MainActivity:

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Provider;
using System.IO;

using Environment = Android.OS.Environment;
using Path = System.IO.Path;
using Uri = Android.Net.Uri;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Util;

namespace CameraIntent
{
    [Activity(Label = "CameraIntent", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape,Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

        String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "AlmacenFotos";

        private Uri fileUri;

        private ImageView imgPreview;
        private Button btnCapturePicture;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            btnCapturePicture = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCapturePicture);
            imgPreview = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imgPreview);

            btnCapturePicture.Click += (s, args) =>
            {
                CaptureamosImagen();
            };


        }

        void CaptureamosImagen()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
            fileUri = GetOutputMediaFile(this.ApplicationContext, IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, String.Empty);
            intent.PutExtra(MediaStore.ExtraOutput, fileUri);

            StartActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
        }

        private Uri GetOutputMediaFile(Context context, string subdir, string name)
        {
            subdir = subdir ?? String.Empty;

            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            {
                string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                name = "IMG_" + timestamp + ".jpg";
            }

            string mediaType = Environment.DirectoryPictures;

            using (Java.IO.File mediaStorageDir = new Java.IO.File(Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(mediaType), subdir))
            {
                if (!mediaStorageDir.Exists())
                {
                    if (!mediaStorageDir.Mkdirs())
                    {
                        throw new Exception("No");
                    }
                }

                return Uri.FromFile(new Java.IO.File(GetUniquePath(mediaStorageDir.Path, name)));
            }
        }

        string GetUniquePath(string path, string name)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(name);
            if (ext == String.Empty)
                ext = ".jpg";

            name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name);

            string nname = name + ext;
            int i = 1;

            while (File.Exists(Path.Combine(path, nname)))
                nname = name + "_" + (i++) + ext;

            return Path.Combine(path, nname);

        }


        protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode,  Result resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            if (!Debug.IsDebuggerConnected)
            {
                Debug.WaitForDebugger();
                Log.Debug("Debug", "Debug Starts");
            }

            base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (!Debug.IsDebuggerConnected)
            {
                Debug.WaitForDebugger();
                Log.Debug("Debug", "Debug Starts");
            }

            if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE)
            {
                if (resultCode == Result.Ok)
                {
                    previewCapturedImage();
                } else if (resultCode == Result.Canceled)
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, "Canceled", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                } else
                {
                    Toast.MakeText(this.ApplicationContext, "Ok", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                }
            }
        }

         void previewCapturedImage()
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.InSampleSize = 8;

            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(fileUri.Path, options);

            imgPreview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

And Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCapturePicture"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tomar Foto"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Preview"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgPreview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I would be very glad, if I get any help. :-)